# Hide or Remove the Content TV from a template in ModX Revo Backend?

Tags: content-management-system, modx, modx-revolution

I have a resource in ModX Revolution and I'm using some TVs but not the 'content' TV. So, it is not used & it confuses users who insert content into it which is not supposed to be displayed on the frontend.

How do I hide or remove the 'content' input from a particular template in ModX Revolution backend?

Comment: This is an old post, but `*content` is no longer referred to as a TV in MODX (hasn't been for *many* years). It is the `content` "field" of the resource. TVs are something else. It's an important distinction, because actual TVs are handled and stored in different DB tables than the resource fields, and TVs are MODX objects, while the resource fields are not. There are a number of other differences between the two. The use of Form Customization to hide the `content` field is still correct, however.

Answer (score 3):

Fishcake is right, you should utilize the builtin [form customization](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Customizing+the+Manager) for this.

You have to:

1. Go to Security -> Form Customization
2. Create a new form customization profile.
3. Edit your newly created profile (right click).
4. Create a new form customization set for the 'Create'-Action.
5. Edit this set (right click).
6. Choose the template you want to restrict the customization to (other constraints are possible, too).
7. Remove the tick beneath `modx-resource-content` (Set information and fields tab).
8. Create another form customization set for the 'Update'-Action and repeat steps 5 - 7.

constraints. Have a look at the [form customization sets](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Form+Customization+Sets) documentation for a more lengthy explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this in Evolution using a plugin called [ManagerManager](http://modx.com/extras/package/managermanager).....a quick search later.....seems it is now native functionality to Modx Revolution: [Customizing the manager](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Customizing+the+Manager)